# Can't get forkJoin to fire

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm building a guard in Angular where I need to make two different HTTP requests, and based on both, determine whether to proceed or not. I noticed `forkJoin` is the right way to do this, but I can't get mine to fire.

In my code, I have:

```
this.userService.watchCurrentUser().subscribe(data => { console.log(data) });
this.orgService.watchOrg().subscribe(data => { console.log(data) });
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.userService.watchCurrentUser(),
    this.orgService.watchOrg()
).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The first two subscriptions were added later to test if the calls were actually firing, and they are; I see the logs from them. But I never see a lot from the `forkJoin`.

I import it at top of my file:

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

Is there something else I'm missing in order to use `forkJoin`?

Answer (score 3):

`Observable.forkJoin()` requires all source Observables to emit at least one item and to complete.

Are you sure both of your source Observables complete?

If they don't (and based on their internal logic they can't) maybe you'd rather use `zip()` or `combineLatest()`.

Comment: They do both fire; I suspect that might be the problem, which is why I added the subscribes to the top, and I see them both emit 2 values actually (I'm calling them elsewhere as well). I end up seeing 4 logs (2 each from the 2 at top) but none from the forkJoin itself. Both of those calls are just wrappers for HTTP requests, so barring the time it takes to return, both should emit, as far as I understand.

Comment: I don't know what you code should do when I can't test it myself but if you're sure they both emit and you know you always want only one item you can chain them with `take(1)` that completes after receiving the first value.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is I need both HTTP requests to complete, as I need the data from both to determine how to proceed. Is there more data I can give you to help root out the issue? As I mentioned, they're really just wrappers for HTTP calls, with a bit of caching built in.

Comment: As Martin said, if you want do a one time job when each of these two Observables emit an item. This probably solves your issue: Observable.forkJoin( this.userService.watchCurrentUser().take(1), this.orgService.watchOrg().take(1) )

Answer (score 0):

In your case, a guard, you just need one result of each stream.
Thus, you should this:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.userService.watchCurrentUser().first(),
    this.orgService.watchOrg().first()
).map(data => {
    let permitted: boolean;
    // check the data you want to.
    return permitted; 
});
```

In the code above the fork is combining the first result of two observables, and both results will be mapped to a boolean.